# R ordering bug?

Tags: r

#### [R Fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=nMfSiD5T&version=1)

```
vals<-c(10.3,10.3,10.2,16.4,18.8,19.7,15.6,18.2,22.6,19.9,24.2,21.0,21.4,21.3,19.1,22.2,33.8,27.4,25.7,24.9,34.5,31.7,36.3,38.3,42.6,55.4,55.7,58.3,51.5,51.0,77.0)

# Standard Order    
# the second and third values should be reversed

order(vals)

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# [1]  3  1  2  7  4  8  5 15  6 10 12 14 13 16  9 11 20 19 18 22 17 21 23 24 25
# [26] 30 29 26 27 28 31
# ------------------------------------------------------------
    

# Reverse Decreasing
# should be the same as the original, but it isn't (it's correct)
rev(order(vals, decreasing=T))

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# [1]  3  2  1  7  4  8  5 15  6 10 12 14 13 16  9 11 20 19 18 22 17 21 23 24 25
# [26] 30 29 26 27 28 31
# ------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need some help in understanding what is happening in R.  I think there's a bug when outputting order and how they are not the same.  Notice the second and third values of both outputs.  Shouldn't the order be `3,3,1` or `2,2,1` or `3,2,1` depending on how order treats the same value?  Regardless.. the third value should have order=1.

Is my understanding correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing `order` with `rank`?

Comment: As joran says, the initial 3 output by `order(vals)` indicates that the 3rd item in the vector is the lowest value. It does not mean that the 1st item in the vector has the 3rd lowest value. So the `1 2` and `2 1` are interchangeable, because the values in those positions are equal.

Comment: I considered it because I read another similar question and I also ran other functions (rank,sort,etc), but then I couldn't explain what (`order`) does, especially given the help documentation.  Even more, I couldn't explain why a reverse of the `decreasing=true` would be different than a standard `decreasing=false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation,

> order returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order, breaking ties by further arguments.

i.e. `order()` returns a set of indices such that `x[order(x)]` is in increasing order, or that `x[order(x,decreasing = TRUE)]` is in decreasing order.

If two consecutive values in `x` are identical, then the order of their indices in the value returned by `order` is immaterial, and will simply depend on what is most efficient and involves the least amount of swapping values around in the internal C code.

Comment: I must be really slow today - something's not clicking.  `vals[ order(vals) ]` does order as I expected and it shows `10.2` in the first position; however, `order(vals)` shows that index having order of `3`.  I understand the swapping of orders for equal values, but I'm still struggling to understand what is happening.  Is there an animation or a more visual representation of what is occurring - I think that might help me and even a colleague that appear to be dimwitted today :) -- thx

Comment: @vol7ron You are fixating on the idea that the numbers returned by `order` correspond to the values in `vals` in the order they appear in `vals`. The `3` returned by `order` means simply that the 3rd value in `vals` should come first, not that the first element of `vals` is the smallest.

Comment: @vol7ron ...another way to look at it is given `x <- c('c','b','a')`, how would you fill in the expression `x[c(...)]` to put them in the right order?

Comment: ACK! It's like the Magic Eye puzzle when you finally see the image for the first time.  Thank you, Joran.  The order number, is the index of the value that should appear.  Right?